# Video record from an IP camera with variable frame rate with opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

First of all, I want to comment on what I'm trying to do.

I have an IP camera connected to my network([FOSCAM 9800p](https://www.foscam.es/descarga/Camaras_IP_Foscam_HD_Exterior_User_manual_en.pdf)) through a router with ethernet cable and from it I am trying to record a video with the RTSP protocol. My intention in the future is to add a small video processing in the middle with opencv but at the moment I want to do the tests to simply record it.

The main problem is that the camera is delivering a variable rate of frames per second, that is, sometimes it does it to 18, others to 22 and so on. When recording the video with a fixed rate of frames per second what ends up happening is that the video plays faster than it should

Something weird that when I run with opencv get (CAP_PROP_FPS) it is returning a big value like 180000.0

To try to solve this problem, what we do is read the frames and place them in a queue. From another process commanded by a timer.Event () we read them and try to write in our video at regular intervals of time in order to obtain a fixed frame rate.

The code is the following:

```
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://"+user+":"+password+"@"+ip+":"+str(port)+"/videoMain")

if (video_capture.isOpened() == False):
  print("Unable to read camera feed")
  sys.exit()

frame_width = int(video_capture.get(3))
frame_height = int(video_capture.get(4))

video_writer =cv2.VideoWriter(output_filename,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MP4V'), fps_to_save, (frame_width,frame_height))
input_buffer = queue.Queue(20)

finished = False

read_frames = 0

def readFile():
    global finished
    global read_frames
    while not finished:
        ret, frame = video_capture.read()
        if not ret:
            finished = True
        while not finished:
            try:
                input_buffer.put_nowait(frame)
                read_frames+=1
                break
            except queue.Full:
                print("queue.Full")
                pass

def processingFile():
    global finished

    written_frames = 0
    repeated_frames = 0

    time_per_frame_elapsed = 0.0

    start_time=time.time()
    ticker = threading.Event()

    while True:
        ticker.wait(time_per_frame-time_per_frame_elapsed)
        time_per_frame_start=time.time()
        try:
            frame = input_buffer.get_nowait()
            video_writer.write(frame)
            writing_time = time.time()
            if written_frames is 0:
                start_time = writing_time
            written_frames += 1
        except queue.Empty:
            if written_frames is not 0:
                video_writer.write(frame)
                writing_time = time.time()
                written_frames += 1
                repeated_frames += 1
        except:
            pass
        total_elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print("total_elapsed_time:{:f}".format(total_elapsed_time))
        if total_elapsed_time>time_to_save_seconds:
          finished = True
          ticker.clear()
          print ("Playback terminated.")
          break
        time_per_frame_elapsed=time.time()-time_per_frame_start
    print("Total readed frames:{:f}".format(read_frames))
    print("Total frames repated:{:f}".format(repeated_frames))
    print("Total frames writed:{:f}".format(written_frames))

tReadFile = threading.Thread(target=readFile)
tProcessingFile = threading.Thread(target=processingFile)

tReadFile.start()
tProcessingFile.start()

tProcessingFile.join()
tReadFile.join()
```

The result is close to what we want, but sometimes we have significant differences in the times. We are doing tests with short videos of about 10 seconds and we get 9.8 seconds of recording.

At first it would not seem a serious problem but the error is cumulative, that is if we increase the time increases so that to record videos of a longer time we have more serious problems.

We would like to know how to solve this type of video recording problems with cameras that deliver frames at variable rates. Is it a good idea to do so?

What can be generating the cumulative error in the times?

From already thank you very much!

Greetings to all!

Answer (score 0):

I can say only one thing. In my own experience OpenCV VideoCapture class works with FFMPEG (OpenCV uses it to decode video) in on-line mode very badly. There was a lot of image artifacts and ffmpeg internal errors. But VideoCapture perfectly works with USB cameras. I solved problem with on-line capture from IP-camera with XSplit Broadcaster. This package is able to emulate a USB-camera via physical IP-camera. The only limitation is resizing of camera frame to 640*480 size. Basic license of XSplit Broadcaster is absolutely free

Comment: Hi, I understand, but it is not what I need, at some point I have to do a video processing and I need to process from the 2 cameras. 

I will consider the option to do some tests, thank you very much! PS: I'm also evaluating moving to c ++